# How to create an Austrian flag in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create the Austrian flag using turtle graphics. Here is my sample code:

```
 import turtle

def rectangle(t,wdth,ht,c):
 t.fillcolor(c)
 t.begin_fill()
 for i in range(2):
    t.forward(ht)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(wdth)
    t.left(90)
 t.end_fill()

def rectangle2(t,wdth,ht,c):
 t.fillcolor(c)
 t.begin_fill()
 for i in range(2):
    t.forward(ht)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(wdth)
    t.left(90)
 t.end_fill()

def flag():
 flag = turtle.Turtle()
 rectangle(flag,50,250,"red")

turtle.up()

def flag2():
 flag= turtle.Turtle()
 rectangle(flag, 50, 250, "white")

flag()
flag2()
turtle.done()
```

My code creates a single red rectangle, which I intended to be the bottom third of the flag. I wanted the turtle to move upward and become the middle portion of the Austrian flag which is a white rectangle.

My code creates the red rectangle as intended, and then the turtle recolors the red rectangle white. This leaves me with a single white rectangle instead of a red rectangle and a white rectangle on top of it.

Comment: use `goto(x,y)` or `forwar/left/right` to move in correct place. You may need  `penup`, `pendown`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I replaced `width` with `height` as @cdlane corretly pointed out in the comment.

---

Use `forward/left/right` or `goto(x, y)` to move turtle in correct place before you draw white rectangle.

```
import turtle

def rectangle(height, width, color):
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

rectangle(50, 250, "red") # bottom red

turtle.left(90)     #
turtle.forward(50)  # go 50 pixel up
turtle.right(90)    # 

rectangle(50, 250, "white") # middle white

turtle.left(90)     #
turtle.forward(50)  # go 50 pixel up
turtle.right(90)    #

rectangle(50, 250, "red") # top red

turtle.done()
```

Comment: I know it's ultimately contrary, but haven't you and the OP inverted the generally understood concept of *width* and *height*?

Comment: @cdlane you are right - I didn't check them, I only renamed them to use more readable variables :)

Answer (score 0):

Three thoughts: you're making it harder than necessary; you need to lookup the Austrian flag in Wikipedia to get the proper aspect ratio; there's more than one way to do it.

First, let's simplify and clean up your code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

HEIGHT = 120
WIDTH = 3 * HEIGHT / 2

def rectangle(turtle, width, height, color):
    turtle.fillcolor(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def flag(turtle):
    turtle.pencolor('black')
    rectangle(turtle, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 'white')
    rectangle(turtle, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 3, 'red')
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 2 * HEIGHT / 3)
    rectangle(turtle, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 3, 'red')

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)

screen = Screen()

flag(yertle)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

But for blocks of color like this, I prefer *stamping* to *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

HEIGHT = 120
WIDTH = 3 * HEIGHT / 2

STAMP_SIZE = 20

def flag(turtle, width, height):
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.color('black', 'white')
    turtle.shapesize(height / STAMP_SIZE, width / STAMP_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

    turtle.color('black', 'red')
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - height / 3)
    turtle.shapesize(height / 3 / STAMP_SIZE, width / STAMP_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 2 * height / 3)
    turtle.stamp()

yertle = Turtle('square', visible=False)

screen = Screen()

flag(yertle, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

And finally, let's reduce it to really simple turtle logic:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

import tkinter as _
_.ROUND = _.BUTT

HEIGHT = 120
WIDTH = 3 * HEIGHT / 2

def flag(turtle, width, height):
    turtle.pensize(height)
    turtle.color('red')
    turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.pensize(height / 3)
    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.backward(width)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

flag(yertle, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]